# How to check an input string in bash it's in version format (n1.n2.n3)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I've written an script that updates a version on a certain file. I need to check that the input for the user is in version format so I don't finish adding number that are not needed in those important files. The way I have done it is by adding a new value version_check which where I delete my regex pattern and then an if check.

```
version=$1
version_checked=$(echo $version | sed -e '/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]/d')

if [[ -z $version_checked ]]; then
    echo "$version is the right format"
else
    echo "$version_checked is not  in the right format, please use XX.XX.XX format (ie: 4.15.3)"
    exit
fi
```

That works fine for XX.XX and XX.XX.XX but it also allows XX.XX.XX.XX and XX.XX.XX.XX.XX etc.. so if user makes a mistake it will input wrong data on the file. How can I get the sed regex to ONLY allow 3 pairs of numbers separated by a dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex from:

```
/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]/
```

to this:

```
/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with bash [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ for version in 1.2 1.2.3 1.2.3.4; do
    printf "%s\t" $version
    [[ $version == +([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]) ]] && echo y || echo n
done

1.2     n
1.2.3   y
1.2.3.4 n
```

If you need each group of digits to be exactly 2 digits:

```
[[ $version == [0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9] ]]
```